# Columns getting overflow when start typing in TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make a saving application by using several `columns` and `textfield` like the picture that I show. but when I try to input one of the `textfields`, I get an `overflow` issue. I don't want the entire `column` to be displayed when I input one of the `textfields`, so that there is no `overflow` but I don't know how. I tried replacing the `column` with ```listview, but the entire screen turned white.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kakeiboo/constant.dart';

class BigNotePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: kPading,
      //i've try to replace this column with listview, but the whole screen getting white
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          TitlePage('Big Note'),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TxtField('Income'),
                TxtField('Expenses'),
                TxtField('Savings'),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'WRITE THAT DOWN FOR ME',
                    style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.25),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 250.0,
            child: Text(
              '*if you get another income for this mounth, input the income again.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[how my app look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYRgA.png)

[when i try input the texfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v11l8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the overflow error by adding `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` to your root `Scaffold`.

Example below:

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your Column widget by a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) should solve the problem.

Comment: it works when i deleted the `expanded` widget, how can i use the expanded widget back?